# Reading log4net.Util.PatternString from the config file

Tags: c#, log4net

How to read log4net.Util.PatternString value from the config file?

```
<log4net>
  ...
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\AppLogs\%date{yyyy}\%date{MM}\%date{dd-MMM}.xml" />
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

I have looked at the ILog attributes but couldn't find anything that gives me log file location.

Comment: you need only PatternString or log file name?

Comment: I am interested in PatternString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the log4net config as a xml file and then find the appender -> file en then the value attribute.

or you can try somethink like searching in current appenders:

```
foreach (var r in log4net.LogManager.GetAllRepositories()){
  foreach (var a in r.GetAppenders()){
    if (a is log4net.Appender.FileAppender){
      log4net.Appender.FileAppender fileappender = a as  log4net.Appender.FileAppender;
      .....
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get file name like this:

```
var ap = Log.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders().First(a => a is FileAppender) as FileAppender;
```

It will have `File` and `DatePattern` properties.